# How to give margin between grids in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Next to each other I have 3 div with classes like these:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
```

How can I add left and right margins between these divs? If I add it manually, like margin-left or right 15px, it will break the row and the divs will not be next to each other.

[image: Here is a photo that what i want]

Comment: Try col-md instead col-md-4 ...

Comment: Why? What do you mean?

Comment: Give a try and read the doc again. If you are familiar with flex you will understand right way. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As commented earlier:

> Try `col-md` instead `col-md-4`

with `mx-md-x` to set/remove the margin.  ressource from BS4 : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/ & https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/

demo:

```css
.row>div {
  border: solid;
}

.bg-warning>div:after {
  content: ', no margins avalaible';
}

.col-md:after {
  content: ', margin avalaible.';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row bg-warning text-dark">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md bg-success text-warning">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md mx-md-2 bg-success text-warning">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md bg-success text-warning">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]